# Can an ESP32 connect to a mobile phone via BLE without a mobile app?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I want to program an ESP32 to act like a server, then my mobile phone connects to it via BLE. The ultimate goal is to transmit data with my React Native app.
I've managed to create a connection using React Native, but this requires fine location permission. So I am guessing, if I could connect to the board using the android/iOS UI, my app would not need the permission above. However, when I try to run the ESP with the following code:

```cpp
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLE2902.h>

#define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"

BLEServer *pServer = NULL;
BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = NULL;
bool deviceConnected = false;
bool oldDeviceConnected = false;

class MyServerCallbacks : public BLEServerCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = true;
    };

    void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = false;
    }
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  BLEDevice::init("YourESP32");  // Set your device name here
  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());

  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);
  pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                      CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
                    );

  pCharacteristic->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

  pService->start();
  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->start();
}

void loop() {
  if (deviceConnected) {
    // You can perform actions here when a device is connected via BLE
  }

  if (!deviceConnected && oldDeviceConnected) {
    delay(500); // Give the Bluetooth stack the chance to get things ready
    pServer->startAdvertising(); // Restart advertising
    Serial.println("Advertising started");
    oldDeviceConnected = deviceConnected;
  }
  
  if (deviceConnected && !oldDeviceConnected) {
    oldDeviceConnected = deviceConnected;
  }
}
```

and try to connect to it using the android UI, I am getting the following error:

> Failed to connect to "YourESP32". Check for issues and try again.

Is what I am trying to do feasible?

Comment: What do you mean by "connect to it using the android UI?" What is "the android UI" in this question? (There is definitely no way to do what you're describing on iOS.)

Comment: @RobNapier I mean to connect by going to the Bluetooth settings of my phone and selecting the device. Not by using my app.

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to connect with Bluetooth Classic (generally used for audio or HID devices like keyboard and mice). That's not related to BLE. I don't develop on Android every day, so it's possible I'm misremembering the panel you're describing. Are you certain it's for BLE and not just "Bluetooth?"

Comment: @RobNapier I suspect BLE consumes less energy, so I would ideally like my ESP to use BLE instead of classic. But you are right. I want to use BLE the way Bluetooth Classic connects if that's possible.

Comment: BLE and Classic Bluetooth are barely related protocols with radically different approaches to communication. It has little to do with power usage. There is no such thing as "BLE the way Bluetooth Classic connects." If you want this to be portable to iOS, your only option is BLE in any case. If you want to enable BLE in your app, you will need the appropriate permissions. You cannot bypass that.

Comment: It's not possible. To connect to any Bluetooth device (Classic or LE) your client must know how to communicate with it. Of course, on low-level there is no problem to connect to any Bluetooth enabled device (on, let say, HCI level), however, upper-level applications (such Anroid UI) always need to know how to communicate with your device. As it does not know - you got an error on your cell phone. If your device implements standard profiles (HID, AVRCP, A2DP, etc) then your phone can connect to it without any app, but in your case it is not possible.

Comment: The permissions have changed in Android 12. You don't need location permission anymore. Instead you need the BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission.